# Groovy Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I wanted to try to match the inner part of the string between the strong tags where it is guaranteed that the strong inside the strong tags starts with `Price Range:`.  This text should not appear anywhere else in the string, but the `<p>` and `<strong>` tags certainly do.  How can I match this with groovy?

`<p><strong>Price Range: $61,000-$99,500</strong></p>`

I tried:

```
def string = "<p><strong>Price Range: \$61,000-\$181,500</strong></p>strong";

string = string.replace(/Price.*strong/, "Replaced");
```

Just to see if I could get something to work, but I can't seem to get anything working that is more than a single word, which of course isn't particularly useful since I don't need regex for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problems.

```
def string = "<p><strong>Price Range: \$61,000-\$181,500</strong>?</p>strong";

string = string.replaceFirst(~/<strong>Price Range.*<\/strong>/, "Replaced");
```

This includes the strong tags but it is good enough for my purpose.  Needed `replaceFirst` instead of `replace` and `~` at the start to indicate a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

http://regexr.com?2t9jp

Comment: note that regexr replaced my `<` signs for `&lt;`. hopefully you can get the idea anyway